# visual basic to check for correct date range

Tags: vb.net, date, range

I need to write a VB code to verify whether the input date conditions are in the correct date range, else it needs to return a message to the user to enter the correct dates.

I am writing this query to fetch the date as an input parameter. Hence, I am passing the fromarrdte and toarrdte as inputs. The code used to initialize it is something like this:

```
dim fromarrdte 
dim toarrdte 
dim begdispdte 
dim enddispdte 
fromarrdte = rptfunc.getParameter("from_arrive_dte") 
toarrdte = rptfunc.getParameter("to_arrive_dte") 
Rpt.sections("ReportHeader").Controls("txtfromarrdte").Text = fromarrdte
```

Rpt.sections("ReportHeader").Controls("txttoarrdte").Text = toarrdte

The dates to be checked are `fromarrdte, toarrdte` and `begdispdte, enddispdte`. 
The code I wrote is as follows:

```
Response.write(BetweenDateRange(Date()) & "<br>")
Response.write(BetweenDateRange(CDate("fromarrdte")) & "<br>")
Response.write(BetweenDateRange(CDate("toarrdte")))

Function BetweenDateRange(DatePassed)
   BeginDate = CDate("fromarrdte")
   EndDate = CDate("toarrdte")

   If DatePassed > BeginDate And DatePassed < EndDate Then
      BetweenDateRange = "True"
   Else
      BetweenDateRange = "False"
   End If
End Function
```

But Im getting a syntax error. Please help. Thanks!!

Comment: Use a DateTimePicker with the Min and Max values set to whatever you need them to be.  no need for an error message, the user can only submit a date in the range you specified

Comment: Hi Plutonix. The first date range is from fromarrdte to toarrdte. The next date range is from begdispdte to enddispdte. So both the date ranges are considered.

Comment: Actually I am supposed to include an error message incase the date range is not correct.

Comment: The point is that `the input date` cant be out of range using a DTP.

Comment: Any option to use in plain VB code other than DTP as this is to be written in another application which supports VB?

Comment: Yes it can be done with code.  Give it a try and post a concrete question when you get stuck; right now it sounds like you want someone to write your code for you

Comment: The reason for posting this question is asking help for how to write the code. I have written a rough code which throws an erro. Can u now pls point out the issue with this. thx

Comment: The param to `CDate` should be something representing a date. `"fromarrdte"` is a string.  Also `CDate` is probably the wrong tool for user input, since they could enter "I like pie", use `DateTime.TryParse`

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that `CDate("fromarrdte")` will never evaluate to a date data type.
Since you're using `Response.Write`, I can assume that you're doing ASP.Net. 
I'm also assuming that `fromarrdte` refers to a form field or something.  If that's the case, you would refer to it as `fromarrdte.Text` or `Request.Form(fromarrdte.ClientID)`

Total sidenote, it would be to your benefit - both as a better developer and to make it easier to troubleshoot these types of issues - to add at the top of your code-behind:

```
Option Explict On
Option Strict On
```

This will make sure that your variables and parameters are declared as a type and that your functions return a value of a certain type.
Looking at your code, it's not easy to tell what your variables are.  `DatePassed` could be interpreted by the reader as 'some test passed on a date' or 'the date passed into the method'.  Similiarly, `BetweenDateRange` intuitively would return a boolean value, but you're returning a string.  But without reading the whole function, we wouldn't know that because you're not defining what type it's returning.
To clarify -- You may do something like:

```
Function BetweenDateRange(DatePassed as Date) as Boolean
    '....
End Function
```

Comment: Hi onskee. I am writing this query to fetch the date as an input parameter. Hence, I am passing the fromarrdte and toarrdte as inputs. The code used to initialize it   is something like this:                                                                                                      dim fromarrdte
dim  toarrdte
dim begdispdte
dim enddispdte



fromarrdte = rptfunc.getParameter("from_arrive_dte")
toarrdte = rptfunc.getParameter("to_arrive_dte")
Rpt.sections("ReportHeader").Controls("txtfromarrdte").Text = fromarrdte
Rpt.sections("ReportHeader").Controls("txttoarrdte").Text = toarrdte

Comment: So, I'll reiterate my last paragraph above.  You're declaring these variables without a data type.  It makes it difficult for us on SO to help address the issues.  It will be more difficult for you to troubleshoot a few months down the road, and even worse for the poor soul who replaces you one day.   Is `toarrdte` supposed to be a date?  When you pass it into your BetweenDateRange function, pass in the variable, not a string containing the variable name.   `BetweenDateRange(toarrdte).`

Comment: It is not about declaring variables without a datatype. The toarrdte as well as 'fromarrdte' is given in the format 'yyyymmddhh24miss'.This has been already specified on the front end of the report control. The date is entered by the user as a parameter and hence that particular input format needs to be checked for the correct date range else spit out a message to the user to correct the entry.